# ElasticSearch / Kibana aggregating count by name

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have an elasticsearch structure like this :

```
{
  "metrics" : [
    {
      "name": "nameA",
      "count": 12
    },
    {
      "name": "nameB",
      "count": 45
    }]
}
```

I would like to create a chart in kibana 4 with the sum of "count" aggregating them by name.
Or at least being able to do so in an ES query.
I tried different structures and methods but I can't find a way to do it.

Thanks

Comment: Would it be possible for you to index each metric separately? Meaning one doc would be '   {
      "name": "nameA",
      "count": 12
    },'?

Comment: For performance issues I am not 100% sure, but it could be possible.

Comment: I would recommend storing the data that way, just because it lends itself more naturally to the aggregation process in Elastic. The problem I had when trying to write a query for you was that it would aggregate all the names fine, but separating the count from the entire document may not be possible without a script. On the other hand, if each item in this metrics array you provided is a single document, this aggregation becomes somewhat trivial. I can show you how to write the query for that structure in the answer if you would like.